# WCF service with Ssl Certificate in Azure emulator

Tags: wcf, azure, ssl, localhost, ssl-certificate

I have setup my my cloud using the following
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

and the web role using the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

My problem that when I use emulator I get an error  That the there is a name mismatch between a certificate and the website in this case(127.0.0.1) 
What can be done to solve it.

Comment: Did you get a wildcard SSL for your website?

Comment: @GauravMantri My Certificate is not wildcard should I get one to run it in emulator?

Comment: Let me provide an answer as to how we did it. May be that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two approaches you could take:

1. **Create a separate cloud project for each environment** - This way you could create a self-signed certificate for your development environment and live with the warning that the certificate is not trusted.
2. **Get a wildcard certificate for your application** - This is the approach we have taken for our application (along with the 1st one). Basically we took a wildcard SSL certificate and used that certificate in our application. Then we added an entry in `hosts` file located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` like this:

> 127.0.0.1 dev.cloudportam.com

Next, we added hosts header in our dev cloud project's `csdef` file.

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="dev.cloudportam.com" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="SSL" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8080" />
  <InputEndpoint name="SSL" protocol="https" port="8082" certificate="SSL" />
</Endpoints>
```

Now when we launch the application, it opens up `https://localhost:8082/` and we just change the address to `https://dev.cloudportam.com:8082` and everything works well.

Comment: Thank you! Let me clarify several things: 1) I already have an SSL certificate installed on my machine - can I use this certificate? How? 2) In azure the same certificate is installed (taken from secret store) together with deployment - can I use it?. Should the certificate be changed/ configured with host name where the service is deployed? 3)ssl certificate is used to validate the server to client, what about other side of handshake? -the client should show its certificate to the server - and server needs to validate that the client is ok