# Enabling https browsing on localhost WCF Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, ssl

I inherited a WCF application that is hosted in Windows Azure.  The application is configured to only allow HTTPS connectivity to access the services, so I'm having problems running the code locally to call and debug it.

When I run the app, I run the WCF role in my cloud service:
[image]

When my app starts, I get to browser windows for an http and httpS endpoint

[image]

The http://localhost window exposes a basic service definition page.  The links INSIDE this page point to an httpS endpoint.  The https://localhost page indicates the page can't be displayed.

I tried following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795779.aspx and [WCF service with Ssl Certificate in Azure emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709780/wcf-service-with-ssl-certificate-in-azure-emulator) but to no avail.  Why can't I browse this service with an https URL?  What am I missing?

Comment: To see the service metadata page over https, you need to set the httpsGetEnabled property in the <serviceMetadata> section of your config to true. Can you verify this setting in your config file?

Comment: Thanks @RickRainey, I checked my config file and found that behaviors\behavior\serviceMetadata has httpsGetEnabled="true"